# Beginreceive/Endreceive passing parameter

Tags: c#, .net, udpclient

I'm reading from the udp socket using the following code, which is working well. Now I need to pass the 'received' from recv back to the calling main. How can this be done.

```
   try
        {
          client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), client);
        }


   private static void recv(IAsyncResult res)
    {

        try
        {
            UdpClient c = (UdpClient)(res.AsyncState);

            IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 162);           
            byte[]  received = c.EndReceive(res, ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
            Console.WriteLine(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(received));

            c.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), c);

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In .Net 4.5 you can use [`async/await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) like this:

```
using (var udpClient = new UdpClient())
{
    try
    {
        udpClient.Connect(IPAddress.Any, 162);
        UdpReceiveResult receiveAsync = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveAsync.Buffer));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you need a loop around that?  As far as I can see that code is going to only catch one packet.